# Cannot Find Option for New Web application on Intellij Ultimate

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, web-applications

I have IntellijIdea16.1.2 (Ultimate version). I am trying to create a web application project from scratch and I chose to follow this guide https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-web-application-support.html#new

But I am not getting the option that **Select Java Enterprise** mentioned in Step 3 "Under Additional Libraries and Frameworks, select the Web Application check box. Select the version of the Servlet specification to be supported from the Versions list. " Only thing I see there is Groovy. Can someone tell me what to do to enable the other options in that list? I tried looking at the facets page and even that seems to assume that there are options available which I cannot see on my client.

Similarly I cannot see the rest plug-in mentioned in this page when I search for restful https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/preparing-for-rest-development.html
[image]

Comment: were u able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

open settings, to see the javaee plugins.

if not install, install these.

Then new project will show the options with javaee.

Comment: when i am tick mark on these plugin and trying to Apply . It gives me an error "Unable to apply changes plugins:"Aspect Support"", "Spring Boot" wont be able to load

Comment: oh, that is not the same with me , I just apply these plugins then it worked. Sorry dont know the reason, maybe change another version will be ok. Dont use the newest version.

Comment: Try deleting `disabled_plugins.txt` from the config folder (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

Answer (score 0):

Currently IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 provides Java Enterprise wizard which contains Web Application and REST Service templates, and supports Maven/Gradle out of the box.

[image: Java Enterprise Wizard]