# IntelliJ: Create WebService and no WebApplication option

Tags: intellij-idea

What I'm trying to do is create a simple web service. I'm following [Getting started with Web service](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-to-develop-a-web-service.html).

1. Not really sure what "A Web Services facet can be only added as a child of a Web facet" means: What are the steps of web facets that should preceed the steps on this tutorial? Should a web service be created as a new module of a web facet project?
2. "Under Additional Libraries and Frameworks, select the Web Application checkbox": when creating a new project (or module), there is no such checkbox, see image below (also [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198678/cannot-find-option-for-new-web-application-on-intellij-ultimate)).

My IntelliJ Ultimate version is 2021.3 (fresh install).

Under `File-Settings->Plugins` all `Jave EE` plugins are installed.

If I create a new project (without WebApplication above), I can select under right-click project->Add Framework Support->Java EE->WebApplication and Webservices. If I proceed from there to create a new module, still no WebApplication checkbox.

[image]

Comment: If you need simplest possible web service then go with JAX-RS https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html#new_project.

Do you mean actually XML-based web service with JAX-WS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a SOAP WebService then start with New Project - Java Enterprise and choose Web application.

[image]

Here I use GlassFish 5.1 and JDK 1.8.

On the next step add dependency on JAX-WS:

[image]

Then, add your WebService class:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class HelloWebService {
  @WebMethod
  public String sayHello(String name) {
    return "Say Hello to " + name;
  }
}
```

Now, you can run GlassFish deployment:

[image]

Important: check the web service URL in GlassFish Log tab:

[image]

Finally, you will be able to see web service page:

[image]

Comment: Can I run this from command line?

Comment: Yes, you can build a WAR file, copy it to GlassFish and then run `asadmin` util to run server. See also embedded GlassFish plugin for Maven in this demo: https://github.com/swsmile/java-soap-demoUsingJaxWS

Comment: Actually http://localhost:8080/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloWebServiceService returns 404 (HelloWebService too).  http://localhost:8080/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ returns "Hello World!" and "Hello Servlet"

Comment: It should not be localhost, get URL from GlassFish Log tab, as I've mentioned in the response. Even on the screenshot it is not localhost, GlassFish binds SOAP to host name.

Comment: There is no url in GlassFish Log tab but substituting localhost with my machines host name gives same 404 (but host_name:8080/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT returns "Hello World").

Comment: I've added GlassFish Log tab screenshot from my project to the response. You may also try to remove Servlet and JSP files. May be they are somehow affect the deployment.